# cadf vs adf on residuals

Tags: statistics, matlab

I was wondering how I could interpret the results from the Spatial Econometric library's cadf and adf.
Running cadf(TS1,TS2,0,1), I obtain the following:

```
Augmented DF test for co-integration variables:       
CADF t-statistic        # of lags   AR(1) estimate 
     -5.20337048                1        -0.037845 

   1% Crit Value    5% Crit Value   10% Crit Value 
          -5.287           -4.728           -4.462
```

I then regress with: res = ols(TS1,TS2);
And finally, I run adf(res.resid,0,1):

```
Augmented DF test for unit root variable:                 
 ADF t-statistic       # of lags   AR(1) estimate 
       -4.939345               1         0.965756 

   1% Crit Value    5% Crit Value   10% Crit Value 
          -3.458           -2.871           -2.594
```

Why is the AR(1) estimate different between cadf and adf (1-0.965756 = 0.034244) ?

Thank you

Comment: Since you got no response in a week, you may want to migrate the question to stats.SE. (In that case, flag for moderator's attention).

Comment: I guess I solved the issue. I found a small glitch in the http://www.spatial-econometrics.com/ library that caused the inconsistency in my results. Thanks!

Comment: can you tell us what's the glitch?